# Small Apps API - Can the app transfer data between Small App and the main app?

Tags: sony

I am trying to understand data transfer between a main app which is modified as a small app (Sony SDK API) and an app running as a normal android app. Is that possible. Will they be using the same process ID or do we need to use some common storage accessible to both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding small app support for an existing app it is basically like adding a widget. Data transfer is perfectly possible between the small app and 'main app' since they are effectively from the same service/process.